# Comparison of wave nature of light and sound

Tags: waves, visible-light, acoustics

Let two people A and B be standing around a corner, such that none of them can see the other. If A shouts, we know that B can hear it and the vice versa is true as well. 
My doubt is why does this happen given that both light and sound travel as waves and light is unable to reach B from A then how do sound waves do it? 
Is it because in this experiment light behaves like a ray and not wave or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2):

Sound waves can travel through solid substances and they can also reflect (echo) off other surfaces. Also, because they have relatively larger wavelengths, they can diffract around obstructions. Visible light waves do not travel (as easily) through most solids and diffraction is a lot more subtle.

Hence with sound, you do not need a clear line of sight to hear someone.

Comment: The waves don't need to go through the solid object.  Their wavelength is large enough to have significant diffraction. If they did travel through the wall you need to put your ear to the wall to hear them due to large impedance mismatch.

Comment: Light can and does diffract around obstructions.  I think the issue is one of scale.

Answer (score 0):

Because the sound wavelength is vastly longer than the light wavelength the diffraction pattern behind the corner of the wall is much wider for sound. Because of this the diffracted (behind the wall) portion is much higher in amplitude for sound as the angle wrt the wall increases.  Note that light is also diffracted behind the corner but rapidly falls off in amplitude as the angle wrt the wall increases.